# failed to resolve gradle error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

that is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mabna.hearthurt"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
//    compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:+'
//    compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
}
```

but this error occured:
error(32,13) failed to resolve: com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.1
also for:
compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:+'
compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
and other external dependencies error occured.
i have sample of com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:+ and com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.1 and other dependencies compiled with no error.
so what is the problem

Comment: call stable `compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'` & `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'`

Comment: Did you solve this ?

Comment: Same error ??? post please

Comment: is there any problem if set `buildToolsVersion "23.1.0"`

Comment: I mean same case #Solivan ?

Comment: @IntelliJ Amiya it is very strange!!! I solved in this way: i made a new test project in another path and then inserted the line `code`compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0' `code` in it and sync it. then synced my main project and error for picasso cleaned!!! but error for `code`compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3'`code` remained so did same for this line and error for this line cleaned also! I dont know why but this worked!do u know what is my project settings problem?

Comment: See my edited answer .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At First Remove `+` calling from **Gradle**

**Do**

```
compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0' // Instead yours
```

**Edit**

Call `multiDexEnabled true`

```
defaultConfig {


    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Then **`Clean-Rebuild-Sync`** in your Project.

> Dependencies is a virtual folder where IDE shows what JAR files the
>   project depends on.

@Solivan I guess it's **packaging bug** . Whenever you create a new project  then this bugs omitted .

Comment: Hope this helps you .

Comment: Ok. thanks for ur help. but why packaging bug accuses and how can i fix it in my main project without making any new project?